# how to get all attributes of inner class as part of the outer class in java while converting to json

Tags: java, jpa, serialization

I have an entity in java as following :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ENTITY_MASTER")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class EntityMaster implements Serializable
{
   @Id
private EntityMasterPK entityMasterPK;

public EntityMasterPK getEntityMasterPK() {
    return entityMasterPK;
}

public void setEntityMasterPK(EntityMasterPK entityMasterPK) {
    this.entityMasterPK = entityMasterPK;
}

@Column(name="ENTITY_BUSINESS_NAME")
private String entityBusinessName;

@Column(name="ENTITY_BUSINESS_NAME_ALT_LANG")
private String entityBusinessNameAltLang;

@Column(name="IS_ACTIVE")
private String isActive;

@Column(name ="GROUP_NAME")
private String groupName;

@Column(name="ENTITY_DESCRIPTION")
private String entityDescription;

@Column(name="IS_SURROGATE")
private String isSurrogate;

@Column(name="IS_GL_ENTITY")
private String isgL;

@Column(name="RECORD_DELETE_ALLOWED")
private String recordDeleteAllowed;

@Column(name="IS_RPF_REQUIRED")
private String isRpfRequired;

@Column(name="LOCK_REQUIRED")
private String lockRequired;

public String getIsRpfRequired() {
    return isRpfRequired;
}

public void setIsRpfRequired(String isRpfRequired) {
    this.isRpfRequired = isRpfRequired;
}

public String getLockRequired() {
    return lockRequired;
}

public void setLockRequired(String lockRequired) {
    this.lockRequired = lockRequired;
}

public String getRecordDeleteAllowed() {
    return recordDeleteAllowed;
}

public void setRecordDeleteAllowed(String recordDeleteAllowed) {
    this.recordDeleteAllowed = recordDeleteAllowed;
}

public String getIsgL() {
    return isgL;
}

public void setIsgL(String isgL) {
    this.isgL = isgL;
}

@Embeddable
public static class EntityMasterPK implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name="SOLUTION_ID")
    private Integer solutionId;

    @Column(name="ENTITY_NAME")
    private String entityName;

    public Integer getSolutionId() {
        return solutionId;
    }

    public void setSolutionId(Integer solutionId) {
        this.solutionId = solutionId;
    }

    public String getEntityName() {
        return entityName;
    }

    public void setEntityName(String entityName) {
        this.entityName = entityName;
    }

}
public String getEntityBusinessName() {
    return entityBusinessName;
}

public void setEntityBusinessName(String entityBusinessName) {
    this.entityBusinessName = entityBusinessName;
}

public String getEntityBusinessNameAltLang() {
    return entityBusinessNameAltLang;
}

public void setEntityBusinessNameAltLang(String entityBusinessNameAltLang) {
    this.entityBusinessNameAltLang = entityBusinessNameAltLang;
}

public String getIsActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setIsActive(String isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public String getGroupName(){
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName){
    this.groupName=groupName;
}

public String getIsSurrogate(){
    return isSurrogate;
}

public void setIsSurrogate(String isSurrogate){
    this.isSurrogate=isSurrogate;
}

public String getEntityDescription(){
    return entityDescription;
}

public void setEntityDescription(String entityDescription){
    this.entityDescription=entityDescription;
}
}
```

I want to serailize this class in a json format to send to my front-end
when i convert it to json i get something like  : `{"entityBusinessName":"..","groupName":"abbc","entityMasterPK":{"solutionId":"100","entityName":"abcd"},..}`

how can i get the variables of entityMasterPk also in the main json as in I want my json to look something like this : `{"entityBusinessName":"..","groupName":"abbc","solutionId":"100","entityName":"abcd",..}`,
I am using jpa and if anyone with a solution to this please help.

Comment: Create a data transfer object with all the fields you want at the front end. Set your object variables manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by getter and setter like this code but not sure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ENTITY_MASTER")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class EntityMaster implements Serializable
{
   @Id
private EntityMasterPK entityMasterPK;

public EntityMasterPK getEntityMasterPK() {
    return entityMasterPK;
}

public void setEntityMasterPK(EntityMasterPK entityMasterPK) {
    this.entityMasterPK = entityMasterPK;
}
@Column(name="ENTITY_BUSINESS_NAME")
private String entityBusinessName;

@Column(name="ENTITY_BUSINESS_NAME_ALT_LANG")
private String entityBusinessNameAltLang;

@Column(name="IS_ACTIVE")
private String isActive;

@Column(name ="GROUP_NAME")
private String groupName;

@Column(name="ENTITY_DESCRIPTION")
private String entityDescription;

@Column(name="IS_SURROGATE")
private String isSurrogate;

@Column(name="IS_GL_ENTITY")
private String isgL;

@Column(name="RECORD_DELETE_ALLOWED")
private String recordDeleteAllowed;

@Column(name="IS_RPF_REQUIRED")
private String isRpfRequired;

@Column(name="LOCK_REQUIRED")
private String lockRequired;

//====this code =====
@Column(name="SOLUTION_ID")
private Integer getSolutionId() {
    return entityMasterPK.getSolutionId();
}

private void setSolutionId(Integer solutionId) {
    entityMasterPK.setSolutionId(solutionId);
}


@Column(name="ENTITY_NAME")
private String getEntityName() {
    return entityMasterPK.getEntityName();
}

private void setEntityName(String entityName) {
    entityMasterPK.setEntityName(entityName);
}
//======end code ======
public String getIsRpfRequired() {
    return isRpfRequired;
}

public void setIsRpfRequired(String isRpfRequired) {
    this.isRpfRequired = isRpfRequired;
}

public String getLockRequired() {
    return lockRequired;
}

public void setLockRequired(String lockRequired) {
    this.lockRequired = lockRequired;
}

public String getRecordDeleteAllowed() {
    return recordDeleteAllowed;
}

public void setRecordDeleteAllowed(String recordDeleteAllowed) {
    this.recordDeleteAllowed = recordDeleteAllowed;
}

public String getIsgL() {
    return isgL;
}

public void setIsgL(String isgL) {
    this.isgL = isgL;
}

@Embeddable
public static class EntityMasterPK implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name="SOLUTION_ID")
    private Integer solutionId;

    @Column(name="ENTITY_NAME")
    private String entityName;

    public Integer getSolutionId() {
        return solutionId;
    }

    public void setSolutionId(Integer solutionId) {
        this.solutionId = solutionId;
    }

    public String getEntityName() {
        return entityName;
    }

    public void setEntityName(String entityName) {
        this.entityName = entityName;
    }

}
public String getEntityBusinessName() {
    return entityBusinessName;
}

public void setEntityBusinessName(String entityBusinessName) {
    this.entityBusinessName = entityBusinessName;
}

public String getEntityBusinessNameAltLang() {
    return entityBusinessNameAltLang;
}

public void setEntityBusinessNameAltLang(String entityBusinessNameAltLang) {
    this.entityBusinessNameAltLang = entityBusinessNameAltLang;
}

public String getIsActive() {
    return isActive;
}

public void setIsActive(String isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public String getGroupName(){
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName){
    this.groupName=groupName;
}

public String getIsSurrogate(){
    return isSurrogate;
}

public void setIsSurrogate(String isSurrogate){
    this.isSurrogate=isSurrogate;
}

public String getEntityDescription(){
    return entityDescription;
}

public void setEntityDescription(String entityDescription){
    this.entityDescription=entityDescription;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Jackson or something like that. So what I did was I made a demo class

```
public static class Jack implements Serializable{

        private String name;
        private SonOfJack sonOfJack;
        public Jack(String name, String id, String topic) {
            this.name = name;
            sonOfJack = new SonOfJack(id, topic);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public SonOfJack getSonOfJack() {
            return sonOfJack;
        }

        public static class SonOfJack implements Serializable{
            private String id, topic;

            public SonOfJack(String id, String topic) {
                this.id = id;
                this.topic = topic;
            }

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public String getTopic() {
                return topic;
            }
        }
    }
```

Used this class for serializing, like this

```
ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Jack jack = new Jack("abc", "tete", "serialize");
        Map<String, Object> map = oMapper.convertValue(jack, Map.class);
        getCombinedMap(map);
        try {
            String json = oMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map);
            Log.d("json: ", json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And here are the methods used

```
private Map<String, Object> getCombinedMap(Map<String, Object> map){
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = iterator.next();
            if(entry.getValue() instanceof Map){
                Map<String, Object> childMap = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
                getCombinedMap(childMap);
                getChildMapInserted(map, childMap);
                map.remove(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getChildMapInserted(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> childMap){
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iterator = childMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = iterator.next();
            map.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        }
        return map;
    }
```

I know instanceOf is a bad thing to do, but this will serve your purpose.
Here is the output I got.

```
    json:: {
        "name" : "abc",
        "id" : "tete",
        "topic" : "serialize"
}
```

You can put any other object in place of jack, this will convert it. 
Log is used for logging, you can remove that line.